# My PHP form is not accepting data after I added a code to not allow empty data through. What is a better way to code this?

Tags: php

So my form was not accepting empty data and that of course was good, but when I just added a username and email it would accept it without the password.

I thought by adding this piece of code `$username = $email = $password = "";` that it would accept the new entry once all fields were filled out, but instead, now it does not accept any entries even if they are all filled out.

It seems this code I added does not allow any new entries, that was not my intention. What would be a simpler code to do what I am attempting to do here ?

```
<?php 

    include('connection.php');

    if(isset($_POST["add"])) {

        // build a function that validates data
         function validateFormData($formData) {
            $formData = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($formData)));
            return $formData;
        }

        // check to see if inputs are empty
        // create variables with form data
        // wrap the data with our function

        // set all variables to empty by default
        $username = $email = $password = "";

        if(!$_POST["username"]) {
            $nameError = "Please enter a username <br>";
        } else {
            $name = validateFormData($_POST["username"]);
        }

        if(!$_POST["email"]) {
            $emailError = "Please enter your email <br>";
        } else {
            $email = validateFormData($_POST["email"]);
        }

        if(!$_POST["password"]) {
            $passwordError = "Please enter a password <br>";
        } else {
            $password = validateFormData($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // check to see if each variable has data
        if($username && $email && $password) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO users (id, username,  password,   email, signup_date, biography) VALUES (NULL,  '$username', '$password',     '$email', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  NULL)";

            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>New record in database!</div>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: ".$query."               <br>".mysqli_error($conn);
            }    
        }

    }



    /*
    MY SQL INSERT QUERY

    INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email, signup_date,     biography) VALUES (NULL, 'jacksonsmith', 'abc123', 'jack@spade.com',   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Hello! I'm Jackson. This is my bio.');

    */

    ?>




    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

        <head>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <title>MySQL Insert</title>

            <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <!--HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries-->
            <!--WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file://-->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
         </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>MySQL Insert</h1>


            <p class="text-danger">* Required fields</p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post">
                    <small class="text-danger">*<?php echo $nameError; ?></small>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"><br><br>

                    <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $emailError; ?></small>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">  <br><br>

                    <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $passwordError; ?></small>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"><br><br>

                    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Entry">
                </form>

            </div>

            <!--jQuery -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

            <!--Bootstrap JS-->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $name = validateFormData($_POST["username"]);

Looks like `$name` should be `$username` on this line, otherwise `$username` is always going to be blank at the time you check it to decide if you want to perform your SQL query.

Comment: This is the answer. I do think the OP might benefit from using stackoverflow.com for any further programming questions though. (Also read up on SQL injection attacks)

Comment: This makes sense, I will give it a try.

Comment: That was the answer Techie007, you are my hero today.